# update a MutableStateFlow when another MutableStateFlow emits

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

```
val persons = MutableStateFlow<List<Person>>(emptyList())
val names = MutableStateFlow<List<String>>(emptyList())
```

I want to update `names` whenever `persons` emits a new value.
This could be done by observing `persons` like:

```
viewModelScope.launch{
  persons.collectLatest{personList->
    names.emit(personList.map{it.name})
  }
}
```

but I was wondering if there is another way to achieve that, e.g. using flow operators ?

Comment: ```persons
    .map { persons -> persons.map { it.name } }
    .collect { names.value = it }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks a little nicer

```
persons.map{ persons ->
    names.emit(persons.map{ it.name })
}.launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

If there is no need for reactive actions, then a function can be used.

```
val names = {
    persons.map{
        it.name
    }
}
// call
println(names())
```

If it's a class property, even better

```
val names: String
    get() = persons.map{it.name}
```